# Switch screen with screenmanager with python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am making an App for school and need to switch screens in my screen manager ( work with kivymd and screen manager).
I need to switch screens after it checks the username and password.
I want to switch them with python code and not in the kv file with ""on_press: root.manager.current = 'Login'"".

In def verify i tried it with "sm.current_screen = 'Main'"  but it does not work.

can somebody help me?

````
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class RegisterScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Change(Screen):
    pass


class ShowObj(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='Login'))
sm.add_widget(RegisterScreen(name='Register'))
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='Main'))
sm.add_widget(Change(name='change'))
sm.add_widget(Change(name='Show'))


class GipApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        self.username = "unknown"
        return screen


    def verify(self, username, password):
        if username != "" and password != "":
            for row in MySqlNames:
                if row[0].strip() == username:
                    sql = "SELECT Password from ID191774_6itn1project7.Users where Username = %s "
                    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
                    TestPassword = mycursor.fetchall()
                    for row3 in TestPassword:
                        if row3[0].strip() == password:
                            print("inloggen is gelukt")
                            self.username = username
                            print(self.username)
                            sm.current_screen = 'Main'

                        if row3[0] != password:
                            dialog = MDDialog(title="Passwords is not correct.")
                            dialog.open()```
````

Answer (score 0):

The lines in your code:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='Login'))
sm.add_widget(RegisterScreen(name='Register'))
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='Main'))
sm.add_widget(Change(name='change'))
sm.add_widget(Change(name='Show'))
```

are not accomplishing anything since you are not using `sm` in your `App`. You can delete those lines.

Since `sm` is not used in your `App`, the line:

```
sm.current_screen = 'Main'
```

will not change the `Screen`. I suggest you replace that line with:

```
App.get_running_app().root.current = 'Main'
```

This assumes that your `kv` file describes a `Widget` tree with a `ScreenManager` as the root.